# how to configure VirtualBox on windows 10 host to use USB modem for network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

VirtualBox version: 5.1.10
host os: windows 10 home edition.
guest os: Ubuntu server 14.04
internet device: LTE USB Stick Huawei E3372

I need the guest to be able to access internet (it works on NAT mode)
I need guest and host to be able to see each other.

I tried a lot of things from old posts.
NAT is working and let guest reach internet, but still can't reach the host

I went through official documentation:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html
But, it doesn't help for me.

any advice?

Comment: When you say guest can't "reach" the host when it's setup as NAT, by what method are you trying to reach it?

Comment: ping  ..  I get guest ip via "ifconfig" command then try to ping from host.

Comment: If you have the Windows firewall up on your host, by default it is set to block ping requests.

Comment: as per your advice, I configured windows firewall to allow inbound ping. And it works.
but windows can't ping Ubuntu yet! ..  Windows can ping external servers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
Bridging via USB modem is not applicable (don't know why!)
the solution is:
NAT adapter to access internet, and also access the host!
Host-Only Adapter to allow host to access the guest!. But, in order to make it working, I had to add another network interface manually. **without this interface it doesn't work**.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is "bridged adapter" instead of NAT. NAT rather purposefully hides your guest behind a sort of virtual wall that makes communicating with it directly from outside the NAT (which includes the host) somewhat cumbersome. It's useful if you want to limit communication with the guest or you only have one IP available on the host's network.

Bridged adapter, on the other hand, makes the guest a peer of the host and every other device on the network with its own MAC address and IP. If you have DHCP setup on your network (and if you don't know what I'm talking about you almost certainly do) the guest will get it's IP automatically same as your host. If not you can configure it as you would another physical machine sitting next to the host and plugged into the same network.

Bridging the network adapters for a vbox guest is almost always the right choice when you need connectivity between host AND guest AND internet AND/OR other networked computers.

UPDATE: Given the information about your USB modem not showing up as an option in VirtualBox, I'll suggest another solution: Port forwarding. When you port forward on a router you are creating instructions for that router's own NAT. VirtualBox offers the ability to do the same.

Open the settings for your guest in virtual box and, in the network section, make sure the adapter is configured as NAT and not NAT Network (older versions of VBox may not have the latter). Then expand the advanced section below that and click `Port Forwarding`. Click the plus on the right side and it will create a blank rule in the list.

You can name the rule as you please. leave the IP addresses blank. The rest depends on what service you are trying to access on the guest. For a web server on the guest, you would use `protocol: TCP` and `port: 80` (keep host and guest ports the same for simplicity). For Windows file sharing you would use 12 separate rules. Six `protocol: UDP` and Six `protocol: TCP`. Each of those would have the same six ports, one rule each. Those ports are 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, and 445.

Without knowing what services on your guest you are trying to access I can't know which ports you should open. But you can look the correct ports up online.

To connect to the guest's service you then use your host's IP address... not the guest's. VirtualBox will catch the messages coming into the host on that port and re-direct them to the guest instead. Because of this, you may have to change the configuration of some services on the guest to use different ports if you are also using the same service on the host.

Two notes:

The ping command does not use UDP or TCP and cannot be forwarded by VirtualBox in NAT mode. Attempting to ping the guest machine from the host will still fail. However, if you have the correct ports forwarded your guest machine's services will be accessible to the host.

Second, if your modem does not have an integrated NAT of its own your guest machine's services (that you have forwarded ports to) will also be accessible from the internet. Though in that case security is a lost cause because the host machine is already exposed. USB modems really are horrible. If at all possible you should see if you can get a network-enabled modem with an integrated router (which comes with NAT) from your ISP or purchase one yourself.

Comment: I tried "Bridged Adapter" it doesn't work with USB modem. I don't know why, but I'm trying to find a solution. and I tried both DHCP and static IP. 
But, when using Bridged Adapter, VirtualBox give me two options in "Attached to". First is Tap adapter. Second is wifi adapter, I think this is the problem I need to find a way to add another Adapter for USB modem!

Comment: Your solution above can work, though there is a small risk of creating a network loop (which would cause you to essentially DoS yourself and possibly your ISP). The more conventional solution when bridged networking fails is to use port forwarding in NAT mode. I updated my answer with details. If you are satisfied with the results of using your own solution feel free to use that instead. The risk really should be rather small.